# Mobile rendering of page loads full vertical page in tiny view

Tags: css, mobile

I'm building a mobile optimized page for a my site. I'm new to mobile web optimization. 
Everything looks fine on my dev machine, but when I go look at the page on my android mobile browser it looks absolutely tiny because it forces the full vertical section of text to show up in the browser. This does not happen on my desktop browser. Any ideas how I can stop this from happening and have it just show up with the full width in the mobile browser?

Comment: Do you really need jQuery UI and jQuery Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `meta-viewport` tag, try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

The important part is `width=device-width`, this will make sure that your HTML takes-up the full width of the screen. The initial and max scale properties are set to one to disable zooming, just change the `maximum-scale` value to something between one and ten to allow zooming.

Comment: Better yet, don't set maximum-scale at all.  Let the user decide if they want to zoom.

Comment: @cimmanon I would set some type of maximum for your site, the default max lets the user zoom **way** in.